# Uncontrolled Input Error in React Hook Form to an Null value from Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-hook-form

The data coming from Redux first returns null and then it comes back, by the way, useFrom could not update it, so I fixed it by using the reset function. Now when null data comes, the form resews, but this time I get such an error, I couldn't solve it.

Error:

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This
> is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined
> value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or
> uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable

It is actually explained here, I know this error, but I could not understand how to solve it from the field value in useForm.

My code:

```
// ** React Imports
import { useEffect, Fragment } from "react";

// ** Third Party Components
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

// ** Reactstrap Imports
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Form,
  Card,
  Input,
  Label,
  Button,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardHeader,
  FormFeedback,
} from "reactstrap";

// ** Store & Actions
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUserProfile } from "@store/userProfile";

const UserProfile = () => {
  // ** Store Vars
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data } = useSelector((state) => state.userProfile);

  //** ComponentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getUserProfile());
  }, [dispatch]);

  // ** Hooks

  const defaultValues = {
    firstName: data?.firstName,
    lastName: data?.lastName,
    email: data?.email,
  };

  const {
    control,
    setValue,
    setError,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
  });

  //** ComponentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    reset({
      firstName: data?.firstName,
      lastName: data?.lastName,
      email: data?.email,
    });
  }, [data, reset]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader className="border-bottom py-2">
          <CardTitle tag="h4">User Account</CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardBody className="py-2 my-25">
          <Form className="mt-2 pt-50" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Row>
              <Col sm="6" className="mb-1">
                <Label className="form-label" for="firstName">
                  First Name
                </Label>
                <Controller
                  name="firstName"
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <Input
                      id="firstName"
                      placeholder="John"
                      invalid={errors.firstName && true}
                      {...field}  //* *****
                    />
                  )}
                />
                {errors && errors.firstName && (
                  <FormFeedback>Please enter a valid First Name</FormFeedback>
                )}
              </Col>
              <Col sm="6" className="mb-1">
                <Label className="form-label" for="lastName">
                  Last Name
                </Label>
                <Controller
                  name="lastName"
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <Input
                      id="lastName"
                      placeholder="Doe"
                      invalid={errors.lastName && true}
                      {...field} //* *****
                    />
                  )}
                />
                {errors.lastName && (
                  <FormFeedback>Please enter a valid Last Name</FormFeedback>
                )}
              </Col>
              <Col sm="6" className="mb-1">
                <Label className="form-label" for="login-email">
                  Email
                </Label>
                <Controller
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <Input
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="john@example.com"
                      invalid={errors.email && true}
                      {...field} //* *****
                    />
                  )}
                />
                {errors.email && (
                  <FormFeedback>{errors.email.message}</FormFeedback>
                )}
              </Col>
              <Col className="mt-2" sm="12">
                <Button type="submit" className="me-1" color="primary">
                  Save changes
                </Button>
                <Button
                  color="secondary"
                  outline
                  onClick={() => {
                    setValue("firstName", data?.first_name);
                    setValue("lastName", data?.last_name);
                    setValue("email", data?.email);
                  }}
                >
                  Discard
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default UserProfile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added defaultValue prop and solved.

```
  <Col sm="6" className="mb-1">
                    <Label className="form-label" for="login-email">
                      Email
                    </Label>
                    <Controller
                      id="email"
                      name="email"
                      defaultValue="" // This is solution.
                      control={control}
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <Input
                          type="email"
                          placeholder="john@example.com"
                          invalid={errors.email && true}
                          {...field} //* *****
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                    {errors.email && (
                      <FormFeedback>{errors.email.message}</FormFeedback>
                    )}
                  </Col>
```